# .net How can set the anonymous type for IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to Convert a `Ienumerable<T>` to a dataset. For this i need to write a common fnction to convert any IEnumerable type to Dataset. For this I need to set anonymous type.
Here is the Code

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(Object alist)
    {
        String AssemblyName  = "DataAccessLayer";
        String ClassName = "sptblSystemPreference_GetListResult";
        Type ObjType = Type.GetType(ClassName + "," + AssemblyName);

//Below line working fine... But how can I implement ObjType in the IEnumerable
        IEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.sptblSystemPreference_GetListResult> objList1 = (IEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.sptblSystemPreference_GetListResult>)alist;
        List<DataAccessLayer.sptblSystemPreference_GetListResult> objList = objList1.ToList();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        if (objList[0] != null)
        {
            dt.TableName = objList[0].GetType().Name;
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] propInfo = objList[0].GetType().GetProperties();
            for (int PropertyCount = 0; PropertyCount < propInfo.Length; PropertyCount++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(propInfo[PropertyCount].Name);
            }
            for (int row = 0; row < objList.Count; row++)
            {
                DataRow dr;
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int PropertyCount = 0; PropertyCount < propInfo.Length; PropertyCount++)
                {

                    Object obj = propInfo[PropertyCount].GetValue(objList[row], null);
                    if(obj!=null)
                        dr[PropertyCount] =  obj;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Se my answer below, but you should also be more precise in what you're asking. There is no question in what you've written above. So it's very hard to know what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this to convert a `IList<T>` to a `DataTable` and documented it on my blog:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties = list.GetPropertiesOfObjectInList();
        DataTable resultTable = CreateTable(properties);

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            var row = CreateRowFromItem<T>(resultTable, item);
            resultTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return resultTable;
    }

    private static DataTable CreateTable(IList<PropertyInfo> properties)
    {
        DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            resultTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, property.PropertyType);
        }
        return resultTable;
    }

    public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesOfObjectInList<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
    }

    private static DataRow CreateRowFromItem<T>(DataTable resultTable, T item)
    {
        var row = resultTable.NewRow();
        var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            row[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item, null);
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

This allows you to write code like `DataTable yourTable = yourList.ToDataTable()`. You can read about it here: [Generic list to DataTable](http://blog.tomasjansson.com/2010/10/generic-list-to-datatable/)